# Process each line which contains a string in several files (Windows Batch)

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, cmd

I'm already very close of what I want and the script runs fine if the files are clean ONLY, but most of them have several comments, few of them inside `/* ... */` blocks aside other crap that need to be deleted.

So I just want to process the lines which have the string `level.waypoints`

Here what I have now:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set findtext="level.waypoints"
for %%F in (*.gsc) do (
  set "out="
  set "i=x"
  > "%%~nF.cfg" (
    for /f usebackq^ tokens^=2^,4^,5^ delims^=[]^=(^)^;^"^  %%A in ("%%F") do (
      if %%A neq !i! (
        if defined out echo !out!"
        set /a "i=%%A, j=0"
        set "out=set flwp_!i! "!i!"

      ) else (
        set /a j+=1
        if !j! leq 3 (set "out=!out!,%%B") else set "out=!out!,%%C"
      )

    )
    if defined out echo !out!"
    set /a "fim=i+1"
    echo set flwp_!fim! "eof"
  )
)
```

I was thinking in add `findstr %findtext%` into these loops but I tryed in many different ways, but didn't succeed yet sadly... Could you help me?

thank you very much!

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve with your script by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40093874/edit) your question! Without reverse-engineering it is not possible to get your intention...

Comment: @aschipfl The FOR is perfect and working fine... I just would like the syntax to change it to ONLY process lines with this string. OR a script to CLEAN everyline from every *.gsc file prior to execute this will also work, which I think will be more simple.

Comment: Did you try to change the set of your `for /F` loop from `("%%F")` to `('find "level.waypoints" "%%~F"')`? is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @aschipfl didn't worked... doing this only return 2 lines and the first is wrong.

Comment: @aschipfl the line become `for /f usebackq^ tokens^=2^,4^,5^ delims^=[]^=(^)^;^"^  %%A in ('find "level.waypoints" "%%~F"') do (` right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant; consider to add the `/I` switch to the `find` command in case the search string is to be treated case-insensitively...

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to delete the lines of each `.gsc` file containing the string `level.waypoints`

```
@echo off 
set "findtext=level.waypoints"

for %%a in (*.gsc) do (
    for /f "delims=" %%b in ('type "%%a"') do (
       echo %%b | find /i "%findtext%" >nul || echo %%b >>"%%~na_New%%~xa"
     )
    move "%%~na_New%%~xa" "%%a" 2>nul
)
```

Comment: aside the crash, I need to delete every line which DOESN'T have that string, and don't want new files, the original could be replaced, no problem about that. thanks!